# How to define .xlsm file saved on Sharepoint as a datasource in Power Query M code?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm working in Power BI.

I have a data source which is an .xlsm excel file stored in a sharepoint folder which I need to bring into Power BI (I can't *Get Data > Sharepoint Folder* as it's set up wrong).

I have another which is a .csv file saved in sharepoint, which I am bringing in already.

The source function in the power query m code for the .csv file is:

```
let Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://
```

I need to add another one similar for the .xlsm file. How can change the m code to bring in the .xlsm file?

I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
let Source = xlsm.Document(Web.Contents("https://
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https:// ... .xlsm"))
```

In case the problem is finding the proper workbook URL, open the workbook in Excel, go to *File - Info - Copy Path*, paste it into Power BI's *Get data - From web* URL and delete the last 6 characters (?web=1).

Comment: Ahh, as simple as defining the 'excel.workbook' instead of trying to define the specific doc type! Thank you so much!